# Change ID of row and reflect this change to all related tables

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl, sql-import-wizard

### Old version

I have a `Person` table and the table `Company`.

both tables have a column `Id` (Identity)

Table Company have Ids of 1 to 165
In the table Person have Ids 1 until 2029

### New Version

In the new version of the system, was created a table `Entity`.
This table contains the records of the `Companies` and `People`

The `Company` and `Person` tables will be **maintained**, referring to the `Entity` table.
**The Id in table `Entity` will be the same in `Company` or `Person` table**

### Question

Both tables have multiple relationships with other tables.
Table `Entity` (as well as others) has a column `ID` (identity).
The problem is that the Id were repeated when the two tables together (It was to be expected).

**How to import without losing relationships?**

### Attempts

I thought of changing the value of Ids in `Company` table, starts from 2030.
Thus the Ids would not duplicate when joining the two tables.

But this creates another questions.

1. How to do this without losing existing relationships?
2. How to change the Id of a row in the table and this is reflected in all tables which it relates?

**I would like to do this using only DDL (SQL Server)**

Comment: Create the new table with 2 extra columns, an old id column and a type column for company or user.  Insert all the values into this new table with the old id column representing the id column from the old table and the type column representing the table type.  Then update all your other tables with the new ids and then drop the two columns because they are no longer needed.  You may need to temporarily drop/change foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of changing the value of Ids in Company table, starts from 2030. Thus the Ids would not duplicate when joining the two tables.

Create foreign key constraints on the Person table to all related tables (or alter the existing foreign key constraints) with ON UPDATE CASCADE. Then update the Person table and change the values if the id columns - these changes will cascade to the related tables.

To stop further problems, maybe change the identity columns in Person and Company to something like identity( 1000, 3 ) and identity (1001, 3) respectively.

However, I think the best idea is to have a different EntityID column in the Entity table, unrelated to PersonID and CompanyID. The Entity table would also have a column called AltEntityID or BusinessKey that contains the id from the other table and that does not have a unique constraint or a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

And if you make small modification to your attempt - add new column, say `newId`, to `Company` and to `Person` to manage relation with `Entity` and leave `id` columns as is. Why this is the simpliest way? Because new columns shouldnot be identity columns, from one side. From the other side, you can leave all logic of relating other tables with `Company` and `Person` intact.